# How to prevent transition on carousel container when reseting its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have applied CSS `transition` to `translateX` on the parent element of my carousel which I animate from `0 to 100%` when clicking the next button, what I want to do however is prevent the animation kicking in when I reset the translate position back to `0` inside my setTimeout. Ideally I would like to set transition to none then quickly remove this when my carousel has reset. Can anyone recommend how I would do this?

**CSS**

```
.carousel {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

**JS**

```
btnNext.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //move carousel to right 100%
        carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(-100%)');

        $('.slide:first').insertAfter('.slide:last');

        setTimeout(function () {
            resetSlides();

            resetCarousel();
        }, 5000);

    });

function resetCarousel() {
        $('.carousel').css({
            'transform': 'translateX(0%)',
            'transition': 'none'
        });

        //now remove inline transition:none style without a transition occurring?
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKv4p/22/

Comment: I made some changes to your code, but I couldnt find a full solution to the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/GKv4p/32/ In this example, you will still see the issue happening while hovering the previous/next arrows. You could remove the `transition` property from `.expose-*`, but that would remove the effect on hovering. I couldn't find a way to fully implement what you want, unfortunately. But maybe with that, you or someone might be able to work something out :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a second css class, "animated". In your CSS you could then have:

```
.carousel {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel.animated {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

In your JavaScript you would then add or remove this extra class in order to add or remove the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I got it working as you want.

The main changes I made were to add the `-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;` to the `.expose-*` classes, and add a delay into `$('.carousel').attr('style', '');`

Ended up with **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKv4p/46/)**

Comment: Note: I'm not sure that first change was even necessary, but I had those changes done already before... You might get it working by just adding a delay to the style clearing :)